# Limit of a polynomial related to greatest integer function

Tags: limits, polynomials

Compute $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {[P(x)]}{P([x])}$, where $P(x)$ is a polynomial with positive coefficients and $ [\cdot] $ denotes the greatest integer function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit is equal to $1,$ since $P(x) = P([x]) + P^\prime(\xi) \{x\},$ where $\xi$ is between $[x]$ and $x$ by the mean value theorem.